# File c++ bin in linux (xubuntu21.10) does not updated after save changes in terminal

Tags: c++, g++

File bin in linux does not updated after save changes in terminal. I do next command in terminal:

```
g++ -o test test.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4)
```

Permissions for file 777. operation system xubuntu 21.10. My file bin after this command does not updated.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right file? How are you checking that the file has updated?

Comment: How do you know? Tell us what you see, not what you think.

Comment: Mind you `test` is a builtin command in bash. https://www.computerhope.com/unix/bash/test.htm